# A working example to observe some concurrency tricks in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

I've been reading on the concurrency, the JMM, and how the operations can be reordered and how an object can be seen only partially constructed from another thread, etc.

I never seen those in "real life". Can I have a working example demonstrating, at least sometimes, those not evident concurrency/JMM tricks? Such an example would be much better than a pure theoretical knowledge.

**I mean, the examples which demonstrate the unexpected behaviour, not the examples of how to do it correct**.

Comment: You might find this interesting http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you, that's indeed one example I was looking for. I can accept this as an answer should you wish.

Comment: How comes people want to close the question as "too broad", not giving anything so far but one small sample :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples are

[Showing when volatile is really needed.](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html)

[False Sharing and Java 7](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/false-sharing-java-7.html)

I suggest you read the rest of those blogs (I wrote the first one)

More excellent blogs in this area.

[Nitsan's Blog](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.co.uk/)

[Dr Hienz Kabutz blog](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/)

[Jack Sharazi's blog](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/)

Last but not least, all these people are members of [Performance Java User's Group](https://plus.google.com/communities/107178245817384004088) with over 1900 members. It has over 100 presentations on performance in Java from over 40 speakers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples(eg:[JavaConcurrency](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html)) available on $subject. And there's a great book on java concurrency [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://amzn.to/1jyE5Kx). Read it if you haven't gone through it yet.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I meant, examples which demonstrates the unexpected behaviour, not the examples of how to do it correct.  Read the book, therefore asking.